# HttpWebRequest: cleaner access to numeric HTTP status codes?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, http-status-codes, system.net.webexception

When I try to get a nonexistent page, or use an invalid HTTP method, [`HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) throws a [`System.Net.WebException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx), with a Status property of [`ProtocolError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx). In its Message property I can see the [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) in parentheses. Fine. But I don't see an integer StatusCode property. Do I really have to parse the Message property to get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [WebException.Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status.aspx) MSDN page:

```
((HttpWebResponse)your_exception.Response).StatusCode
```

The [StatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode.aspx) property will give you an enum that maps to the regular status codes from the HTTP spec.